# Ionic Ion-datetime to database via nodejs

Tags: node.js, date, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

So i am displaying a **datepicker** so people can select their birthdays and from there i send it to my node server and the node server sends it to the database but it doesn't work the format in the database is "**Datetime**" and whenever i send the data from the client it sends like this: "`2012-11-01 01:00:00.000" iso.` But it doesn't update the user it doesn't work so does any have an idea how i fix this?

my html

```
  <ion-item class="settingsItem">
                    <ion-label position="stacked" class="settingsItemFont">Birthday</ion-label>
                    <ion-datetime displayFormat="YYYY MMM DD" min="1994-03-14" max="2012-12-09" [(ngModel)]="date"></ion-datetime>
                </ion-item>
```

my .ts

```
  const headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        const options = {headers: headers};
        const data = {
            date: this.date
        };
        this.http.post('http://localhost:4000/api/tutorial', data, options).subscribe(res => {
                console.log(res);
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
```

Comment: Which date formate is acceptable on server ? Formate the same date formate as server accept.

Comment: which database your using??

Answer (score 0):

you can also try to `date: this.date.substring(0,10);` that will send your first 10 character that means 2011-11-01 only consider and only YYYY-MM-DD are save